# Unable to cast datatable column value to nullable int32

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ado.net

Below is my class definition to get columns details from mssql and mysql:

```
public class Columns
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Datatype { get; set; }
        public string IsNullable { get; set; }
        public Int32? character_maximum_length { get; set; }
        public byte? NumericPrecision { get; set; }
        public Int32? NumericScale { get; set; }
    }
```

Based on [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969(v=vs.110).aspx) i choose **Int32?,byte? and Int32 for character_maximum_length,Numeric position and Numeric scale property**.

Now this works in case of mssql when i fill column details :

```
 cols = con.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions).AsEnumerable()
       .Select
       (
              col => new Columns
              {
                Name = col[3].ToString(),//name of column
                Datatype = col.Field<string>("DATA_TYPE"),
                IsNullable = col.Field<string>("is_nullable"),
                character_maximum_length = col.Field<Int32?>("character_maximum_length"),
                NumericPrecision = col.Field<byte?>("NUMERIC_PRECISION"),
                NumericScale = col.Field<Int32?>("NUMERIC_SCALE")
               }).ToList();
```

I am using same class for filling column details in case of mysql but getting error on  below line : **Specified cast is not valid**

```
  character_maximum_length = (Int32?) col[8] // in case of mysql
```

There is no documentation which states what is the datatype for character_maximum_length,Numeric position and Numeric scale in case of mysql.

I have checked datatype of character_maximum_length like below:

[image]

But i want to keep my **Column class same for both mysql and mssql**.

So how do i solve this problem???

Comment: Maybe you could try to use UInt64? instead of Int32?

Comment: @Steven : Yes that worked but now getting error in case of mssql

Comment: on what line does it break and what's the value you try to cast?

Comment: @Learning you could change **character_maximum_length** to Int64? then  **=  (Int64?) col[8]**. should work for both mssql and mysql?